# I am stuck on the error of "CreationException: Unable to create injector" in playframework:

Tags: scala, playframework

When I start to compile my progress, this error shown out, and I have no idea on this

```
CreationException: Unable to create injector, see the following errors:

1) No implementation for play.api.db.Database annotated with @play.db.NamedDatabase(value=orders) was bound.
  Did you mean?
    play.api.db.Database annotated with @play.db.NamedDatabase(value=test) bound  at play.api.db.DBModule$$anonfun$$lessinit$greater$1.$anonfun$new$1(DBModule.scala:28):
Binding(interface play.api.db.Database qualified with QualifierInstance(@play.db.NamedDatabase(value=test)) to ProviderTarget(play.api.db.NamedDatabaseProvider@75d11445)) (via modules: com.google.inject.util.Modules$OverrideModule -> play.api.inject.guice.GuiceableModuleConversions$$anon$4)

    play.api.db.Database bound  at play.api.db.DBModule$$anonfun$$lessinit$greater$1.defaultDatabaseBinding$1(DBModule.scala:32):
Binding(interface play.api.db.Database to BindingKeyTarget(interface play.api.db.Database qualified with QualifierInstance(@play.db.NamedDatabase(value=test)))) (via modules: com.google.inject.util.Modules$OverrideModule -> play.api.inject.guice.GuiceableModuleConversions$$anon$4)

  while locating play.api.db.Database annotated with @play.db.NamedDatabase(value=orders)
    for the 2nd parameter of controllers.HomeController.<init>(HomeController.scala:19)
  while locating controllers.HomeController
    for the 3rd parameter of router.Routes.<init>(Routes.scala:29)
  at play.api.inject.RoutesProvider$.bindingsFromConfiguration(BuiltinModule.scala:130):
Binding(class router.Routes to self) (via modules: com.google.inject.util.Modules$OverrideModule -> play.api.inject.guice.GuiceableModuleConversions$$anon$4)
```

Here is my @injector code

[image]

And here is my build.sbt (I am not sure is it related or not)

[image]

What should I do right now?

Comment: [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/)

Comment: You tried to inject a named database called "orders". The compiler informs you that there is not database with this name but it has found a Database called "test". I have have absolute no knowledge about scala. But with the given Exception I would create a Database with the Name orders or use the test data base in the Annotation `@NamedDatabase("test")`.

Comment: You should define `db.orders` in your `application.conf` file. Is it defined there?